# Chronoforms - remove validation from field dynamically

Tags: validation, joomla, chronoforms

Is it possible to remove validation `validate['required email']` from a field in my Chronoform dynamically?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your use case a bit? Specifically, why do you want to remove validation dynamically?

Comment: Best you contact the developer of Chronoforms as it regarding a specific extension ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually looking for a way to do it dynamically using Javascript. I read [here](http://www.chronoengine.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=89646&p=311590&hilit=dynamically%20add%20validation#p311590) that you can just add the `required` as normal in the Chronoforms backend and then enable and disable the input as and when required.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the form HTML and insert PHP code to conditionally include the "validate['required email']" text in the form.

Be careful if subsequently editing your form using the form wizard as form HTML customisations can be overwritten.